# How to store an objects in array after method in my class

Tags: javascript, class, object, oop

Please see my code below.

```
class User {
  
  constructor(name, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
   
  }
  
  addUser() {
    users.push(this.name, this.email)
  }
  
}

const userOne = new User ('John', 'john@mail.com');
const userTwo = new User ("Alan", "alan@mail.com");

let users = [];

userOne.addUser();
userTwo.addUser();
```

After method addUser i have array with names and emails but i would like to have an array with objects as below

```
users = [
{ name: 'John', email: 'john@mail.com' }
{ name: 'Alan', email: 'alan@mail.com' }
]
```

How my method addUser should looks in my prototype and if variable users is in correct place or can be store somewhere in Class?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just writing `users = [userOne, userTwo];`?

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for method to my prototype as my template

Comment: It is an antipattern to have a method that mutates a global variable. It goes against the OOP principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing the object properties one after the other, rather than as an object together.

Try this for your `addUser` method:

```
addUser() {
  users.push({name: this.name, email: this.email})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You just need to push each proprieties

```
users.push({name: this.name, email: this.email})
```

If you want to do this automatically you can use:

```
users.push(Object.assign({}, this))
```

Or you cloud just pass the whole object:

```
users.push(this)
```

Anyhow, I would suggest not to use users globally.

Comment: Thanks for your help, both metods are works fine for me !